# CSS: can css applied to <td> and <tr> elements perfectly simulate the style of <div> elements?

Tags: css

I wanted to know if I customize a table with `<td>` and `<tr>` elements in the same way I usually customize `<div>` elements of a page.

I'm asking this because I cannot modify the generated html code, and I would like for example to float the rows to right, or to add padding, margin.

Is CSS working perfectly on `<tr>` or `<td>` elements ? (I am asking you this before to start).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is CSS working perfectly on  or
>     elements ? (I am asking you this
>   before to start).

Yes, you can apply css to any element. By the way, you can choose the direction of TDs by specifying `align="left"` or `align="right"`. No need to float them. You could have provided sample of what you want to achieve though.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what you want to do. If you want to apply custom floating to particular cells (using CSS `float`) you might get crazy results because you mock around with box-model of `<td>` element.

If you want to float the text/content inside, you can always use `text-align:left / right / center`.

Again - if you want to affect **content** of the TD it should be relatively same as if you used `<div>`. If you want to affect **td itself** you might get unexpected results especially around `position`, `float`, `z-index`, `display` CSS attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am asking you this before to start".

That's a bit stupid (no(t too much) offense) don't you think?

If you had give it a try you would have seen that there's no problem. Just be aware that *default style* is not the same and that there are some constraint due to the displaying of table element (which you can get rid of by using the css `display` property).

Comment: yeah I agree on you. But I have to make some decisions about the generated html. And the css come later, so I wanted to know if displaying the content as table is a strong limitation for css.

Comment: In that case fire up your firebug and just try some stuff in live on your webpage ;-).